# Inequality involving joint distribution and marginal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, differential-calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ be a joint density of $X$ and $Y$. Let $f_{X}(x)$ and $f_{Y}(y)$ be the marginal density functions. Is the following inequality true?
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f^2(x,y)dxdy\geq \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f^2_{X}(x)dx\times \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f^2_{Y}(y)dy.
$$

Comment: Could you say a bit about the motivation?

Comment: For discrete distributions this seems not to work try (0.7 0.15) and (0.15, 0) as the two rows of a bivariate distribution where X and Y take two values.

Comment: Martin Cripps, you are right! That is indeed a counter-example. The claim is not true!!! Thanks.

Comment: Regardless of the motivation, it appears that something like the claimed inequality might hold with some universal constant $c$ (just not 1, as the counterexample indicates).